# How to put Case in Where Statement for Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, case

For the query below, I'm trying to pull a specific date range depending on the current day of the month. If it's the 20th or less (e.g. "2/7/2020") then I want the date range for January. Otherwise, I want the date range for February. Is it possible to be done with a case statement? Or there is a better way?

```
SELECT
    account,
    start_date,
    amount
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    CASE
            WHEN (
                SELECT
                    CAST(EXTRACT(DAY FROM sysdate) AS NUMBER)
                FROM
                    dual
            ) <= 20 THEN
                    start_date
            BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'
        ELSE start_date BETWEEN '2020-02-01' AND '2020-02-29'
    END
```

Comment: On a side note: `(SELECT CAST(EXTRACT(DAY FROM sysdate) AS NUMBER) FROM dual)` is nothing else but a mere `EXTRACT(DAY FROM sysdate)`. `start_date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-01-31'` should be `start_date BETWEEN DATE '2020-01-01' AND DATE '2020-01-31'`. The result is a boolean, and this would work, if Oracle featured `BOOLEAN` in SQL, which it doesn't unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by avoiding the case statement and using truncate the date - 20 to the month, e.g.:

```
SELECT account,
     start_date,
     amount
FROM   table1
WHERE  start_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE - 20, 'mm')
AND    start_date < add_months(TRUNC(dt - 20, 'mm'), 1);
```

If you really had to use a `CASE` expression (you can't use a `CASE` statement in SQL), you would need to do something like:

```
SELECT account,
     start_date,
     amount
FROM   table1
WHERE  start_date >= CASE WHEN to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd') <= '20' THEN add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm'), -1) ELSE TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm') END
AND    start_date < CASE WHEN to_char(SYSDATE, 'dd') <= '20' THEN TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm') ELSE add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'mm'), 1) END;
```

N.B. if you're using a function, you don't need to wrap it in a `select .. from dual`, you can use it directly in the SQL statement.

I've also assumed that you want a dynamic range, e.g. if the day of the month is 20 or less, the range is for the previous month, otherwise the current month.

---

ETA: You would use the above two queries if there is an index on the `start_date` column, otherwise you could simply do:

```
SELECT account,
     start_date,
     amount
FROM   table1
WHERE  TRUNC(start_date, 'mm') = TRUNC(SYSDATE - 20, 'mm');
```

Comment: `to_char(SYSDATE, 'dy')` outputs `mon` ([db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=523c4437658b8ec70792308041802469)); you probably want `dd` as the format model (and Oracle will perform an implicit string-to-number conversion) or just use `EXTRACT( DAY FROM SYSDATE)` like the OP does in their question.

Answer (score 1):

Case statements return single values. As such you should pull out the start date and you'll need two case statements.

```
select account, start_date, amount
from table1 where
start_date between 
(case
when (select cast(extract(day from sysdate) as number) from dual) <= 20 then '2020-01-01' 
else '2020-02-01'
end) and 
(case
when (select cast(extract(day from sysdate) as number) from dual) <= 20 then '2020-01-31' 
else '2020-02-29'
end)
```

Comment: You don't need the `(select cast( extract( day from sysdate ) as number ) from dual)` you can just use `extract( day from sysdate )` instead. Also, `'2020-01-01'` is a string literal and is not a date; Oracle will implicitly try to convert the string to a date using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter but each user can set their own value for this format model at any point so you should never rely on the default format and use a date literal (`DATE '2020-01-01'`) or the `TO_DATE` function with an explicit format model instead.

Answer (score 0):

One method subtracts 20 days and then gets the month boundary:

```
where start_date >= trunc(sysdate - interval '20' day, 'MON') and
      start_date < trunc(sysdate - interval '20' day, 'MON') + interval '1' month
```

This approach is index (and partition) friendly -- an appropriate index on `start_date` can be used.  It is also safe if `start_date` has time components.

Note:  You can use `sysdate` without having to use a subquery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `or` operator with `last_day` function as following:

```
Select * from your_table
Where (
       start_date <= trunc(sysdate,'mm') + 20
       and start_date between trunc(sysdate,'mm') - interval '1' month and trunc(sysdate,'mm') - 1
      )
   Or
      (
       start_date > trunc(sysdate,'mm') + 20 
       and start_date between trunc(sysdate, 'mm') and last_day(sysdate)
      )
```

This approach will use index on `start_date`, if any.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

```
    select account, amount, start_date
      from table1
     where (   (    (select cast (extract (day from sysdate) as number) from dual) <= 20
                    and start_date between date '2020-01-01' and date '2020-01-31')
            or (    (select cast (extract (day from sysdate) as number) from dual) > 20
                    and start_date between date '2020-02-01' and date '2020-02-29')
           );
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CASE expressions as BETWEEN operands:

```
SELECT account
     , start_date
     , amount
FROM table1
WHERE start_date BETWEEN CASE
                           WHEN extract(day from sysdate) <= 20
                             THEN trunc(sysdate -interval '1' month, 'month')
                             ELSE trunc(sysdate, 'month')
                         END
                     AND CASE
                           WHEN extract(day from sysdate) <= 20
                             THEN last_day(sysdate -interval '1' month)
                             ELSE last_day(sysdate)
                         END
```